# Document folder on sidebar points to Ubuntu One/Documents

Tags: ubuntu-one, directory

Whenever I click on Documents on the Computer Menu, it directs me to the Documents folder I had in Ubuntu One (which I have uninstalled) and I get the following error message:

Could not find "/home/dposnanski/Ubuntu One/Documents"

how can I change it so it directs me to "/home/dposnanski/Documents" instead ?

Here's a screenshot

[image: Documents folder pointing to Ubuntu One folder]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you got into this situation, but you can fix it by editing `~/.gtk-bookmarks`, or removing the file altogether if you have no useful custom bookmarks in there.

Comment: Thanks, it now points to the right folder.. but it moved to the bookmarks menu instead of the computer menu.. any ideas how I can change that?? Thanks again!!

Comment: @Deli00, what happens if you remove the file completely?